# Redirect all but one file in a directory via httpd.conf / htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

I would like to redirect as such...

```
http://old.com/a/b/ -> http://new.com/y/z/
http://old.com/a/b/file.php -> http://new.com/y/z/
http://old.com/a/b/c/file.php -> http://new.com/y/z/
http://old.com/a/b/anything -> http://new.com/y/z/
http://old.com/a/b/EXCLUDE.php -> http://old.com/a/b/EXCLUDE.php
```

I currently have the following in httpd.conf and it redirects correctly:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /a/b/(.*) http://new.com/y/z/
```

I don't know how to exclude one file from being redirected.

Basically I want all URL's **starting with** "old.com/a/b/" to go to a singe new URL, except I want a single URL to be ignored.

Comment: According to http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html, you don't need the (.*); RedirectMatch replaces the start of URLs, so everything under /a/b/ will be caught anyway. As to your question, how about adding 'RedirectMatch 301 /a/b/EXCLUDE.php /a/b/EXCLUDE.php' before your existing rule? I don't know if it'll work, but it's worth a try.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using a negative lookahead in the regular expression should work:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /a/b/(?!EXCLUDE.php) http://new.com/y/z/
```

If you want the rest of the path to carry over with the redirect, use the backreference $1 as in:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /a/b/(?!EXCLUDE.php) http://new.com/y/z/$1
```

Comment: Before seeing your answer I explored ways to achieve the same outcome with rewrite rules. For anyone who may come across this question wanting a solution using rewrite rules, this appears to work:

`RewriteEngine on`
`RewriteRule ^/a/b/EXCLUDE.php$ - [L]`
`RewriteRule ^/a/b/(.*)$ http://new.com/y/z [R=301,L]`

Answer (score 3):

I know it's been answered but for people who want some RewriteRule stuff:

```
http://old.com/a/b/ -> http://new.com/y/z/
http://old.com/a/b/file.php -> http://new.com/y/z/
http://old.com/a/b/c/file.php -> http://new.com/y/z/
http://old.com/a/b/anything -> http://new.com/y/z/
http://old.com/a/b/EXCLUDE.php -> http://old.com/a/b/EXCLUDE.php
```

---

This should work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/a/b/EXCLUDE\.php) [NC]
RewriteRule /a/b/(.*) http://new.com/y/z$1 [QSA,NC,R=301]
```