# Create a 301 redirect excluding a subdirectory

Tags: apache, redirect

I need to do a 301 directory redirect in my httpd.conf file but exclude a subdirectory within the directory.
Example:

```
RedirectPermanent /redirect/  http://www.mysite.com/
```

But I want to exclude this subdirectory `/redirect/example/`

Any ideas?

Comment: That won’t work with the Redirect directive, you’ll have to do the redirecting using mod_rewrite instead.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814100/redirect-all-but-one-file-in-a-directory-via-httpd-conf-htaccess to avoid mod_rewrite and use `RedirectMatch`

Comment: After working on this on and off for a couple of days, I finally came up with a combination that works:

Comment: RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/redirect/example/.*? [NC]
RewriteRule ^/redirect/? http://www.mysite.com [R=301,L]