# exclude a sub directory from .htaccess 301 redirects

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Can you tell me how I can exclude a specific folder from the 301 redirects set up as below in htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect all but one file in a directory via httpd.conf / htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814100/redirect-all-but-one-file-in-a-directory-via-httpd-conf-htaccess)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/excluded_directory)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```